# Second order derivative with imaginary root r

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

I am doing assigned practice questions, and encountered this:

$y''(x)=-y(x),\,y'(0)=1,\,y(0)=0$

Here's what I tried:

Let $y=e^{rx}$, $y'=re^{rx}$, $y''=r^{2}e^{rx}$

Rearrange the equation ===> $y''(x)+y(x)=0$

Factor out $e^{rx}$, and I have $e^{rx}(r^{2}+1)=0$

Which makes $r=i$, and $y=Ce^{ix}$ for some constant C

I am stuck and need some help for this question.

Am I on the right track? Or did I messed up from the beginning?

Comment: You are on the right track.  $r=i$ or $r=-i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  $r^2+1=0\implies r=\pm i$, so $y=C_1e^{ix}+C_2e^{-ix}$.

Now   use the initial conditions to find $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Can you solve for $C_1$ and $C_2$ and show that $y=\sin x$?